# Retrieving a CI variable outside the CI file in GitLab

Tags: variables, gitlab, continuous-integration

I want to retrieve and use the project information using the predefined variables in GitLab such as CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR.

I want to use that variable outside of the .gitlab-ci.yml file.

I am writing a template so when it's used the file should repopulate with the correct information.

For example, the template includes a .yaml file

```
apiVersion: sample.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: #said team app"my_awesome_app"
  description: #description of app
  annotations:
    backstage.io/techdocs-ref: dir:.
spec:
  type: documentation
  lifecycle: experimental
  owner: $CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR
```

Comment: "I am writing a template so when it's used the file should repopulate"
- What do you mean when the template is used?
- You want this template to be populated inside a running gitlab pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Gitlab variables outside the .gitlab-ci.yml, the way to achieve this is to query them through the Gitlab API

But unfortunately, for the Gitlab `predefined` variables it seems that an API to retrieve them doesn't exist

My proposal would be to create a file with all the variables you require, in your gitlab-ci.yml. Store it the artifacts and retrieve the artifacts through Gitlab API

To achieve this firstly add a job to your gitlab yml, that stores the predefined variables in an artifact E.g

```
store_predefined_variables:
  ...
  script:
    - touch variables.txt
    - echo "CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR=$CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR" >> variables.txt
  artifacts:
     paths:
       - ./variables.txt
```

Next retrieve the **id** of the job with name `store_predefined_variables` https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-project-jobs

```
GET /projects/:id/jobs
```

Finally, use the `job id` to retrieve the artifacts that contain all the needed variables https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#get-job-artifacts

```
GET /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/artifacts
```

Combining the two API calls and utilizing the `jq` command, we can get a one liner that retrieves the artifacts of the most recent job with name `store_predefined_variables`. The artifacts are download as `artifacts.zip`

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 (KHTML,like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0 Safari/534.17" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs/$(curl -s  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs" | jq '[.[] | select(.name=="store_predefined_variables")] | .[0].id')/artifacts" -O artifacts.zip
```

Comment: Hi Tolis, won't it require to commit and push the file again in where we have used the CI variable. Like I have a pipeline which builds the deb package, but what would be the name of deb package is decided based upon the tag release. Once the tag is released, I want that tag name to be there in control file(used to make deb packages) and in gitlab-ci.yml(in this it is still practical as we can access variable in this file). Please see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74799789/how-to-read-content-of-a-file-which-is-received-using-curl-command-in-gitlab-ci